# Can I apply Holder's inequality in this case?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I would like to prove that for any $0<q \leq p$, if $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq ... \geq x_n \geq 0$ then $$\left( \sum_{j=m+1}^n x_j^p \right)^{1/p} \leq m^{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q}}\left( \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^q \right)^{1/q}.$$

This is my proof: by applying Holder's inequality, we obtain
    \begin{align*}
   \left( \sum_{j=m+1}^n x_j^p \right)^{1/p} &\leq \left( \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^p \right)^{1/p} \\
     &\leq \left[ \left( \sum_{j=1}^n (x_j^p)^{q/p} \right)^{p/q} \left( \sum_{j=1}^n 1^\frac{q}{q-p} \right)^{(q-p)/q} \right]^{1/p} \\
     &= n^{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q}}\left( \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^q \right)^{1/q} \leq  m^{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q}}\left( \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^q \right)^{1/q}
 \end{align*}

However, I'm not sure I can use Holder's inequality because $q-p \leq 0$. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not use Holder in this case. Holder would require that $q/p,~q/(q-p)\geq 1$.

Also, your first inequality is too weak. You try to proof that
$$ \left(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^p\right)^{1/p} \leq m^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}} \left(\sum_{j=1}
^nx_j^q\right)^{1/q}. $$
But this is not true, a counterexample is $x_1=1,~x_2=...=x_n=0,~m=2$.

Hint: Try to start like this:
$$\sum_{j=m+1}^nx_j^p \leq x_m^{p-q}\sum_{j=m+1}^nx_j^q \leq \left(\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^mx_j^q\right)^\frac{p-q}{q}\left(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^q\right)$$
If you need further help, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks. I got your hint but I still have no idea to prove my desired inequality. Please  give me more hints.

Comment: I added one more step.

Comment: Now I can prove it. Thank you for your helps. ^^